# Lucene - Cannot find value in field via query

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, luke

I'm new in lucene and I'm trying to find all documents with a exact value in exact field.

In index (using luke) is visible, that field **__r_ani** contains numeric value **567248953**

[image: __r_ani]

But when I try to search in this index, lucene returns no results. I tried these queries:

```
__r_ani:567248953
__r_ani:"567248953"
__r_ani:[* TO *]
```

Is posible, that field has a bad name (beggining with 2 underscore characters)?
Or it is possible, that field has bad configuration? (tokenized, indexed, stored, etc...)?

Edit: I just found, that my collegue is indexing it as **StoredField**. I tried index it as **StringField** and searching now works. I still don't understand, why I cant find it by query, when it is indexed as StoredField.

Comment: Question was edited..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I will use StoredField only, then value is stored, but not indexed. Luke is lying, that value is indexed. After indexing that value to field (with StringField or Double/LongPoint) search works.